# Using sensor to detect current direction which iPhone is pointing to

Tags: objective-c

Suppose we have a coordinate system that its z axis is perpendicular to the ground surface. Then a direction is specified by an unit vector of the system. My question is how to detect the direction pointed by iphone's camera (or something else) by using iPhone's sensor.
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Motion's CMDeviceMotion property `gravity`

```
 @property(readonly, nonatomic) CMAcceleration gravity
```

will give you the devices orientation with respect to your z perpendicular to ground.

```
( 0, 0,-1) - device horizontal face up
( 0,-1, 0) - device vertical portrait, home button at base
(-1, 0, 0) - device vertical landscape, home button on right
```

Then Core Locations' CLHeading  property `magneticHeading`

```
@property(readonly, nonatomic) CLLocationDirection magneticHeading
```

will give you the rotation around z (i.e. orientation with respect to x and y).